# My SQL query to get the values coming in a range intervals depending on the value of other column of the table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am using PHP and mysql, I have the database table as:

```
Code  Price
226   0.001
7565  0.001
7566  0.001
7567  0.001
7568  0.001
7569  0.001
7570  0.001
7571  0.001
7572  0.001
7583  0.002
7584  0.002
7585  0.003
7586  0.003
```

**And i need the output as:**

```
Code  Price
226   0.001
756   0.001
757   0.001
7583  0.002
7584  0.002
7585  0.003
7586  0.003
```

That is if in range of ten, if price comes same them I have to trim it's last value and if different prices comes in range of 10 then my code will be as it is.

As above 226 has single value not having more values between 220 and 229 so we take this value as 226 -  0.001 , And from 7565 to 7569 these numbers are coming in range of 7560-7569 and have same price so i will use grouping for these and get the common value756 and for 7583,7584,7585,7586 these are in range of 7580-7589 but have  two values of price so we can't use group for full range of code so it will be as its. I need trimming only if code coming between a range of ten and have same price.

Let me clear my requirement, i have database of country name , country code,city code and price and i am reading values from excel. In the country field there will be only one value in an excel row like **225 or 2247 or 226** and in the city codes there would  be values corresponding to the countries like **120,123-129, 165-169** may be **1-5 etc..**

Normaly my requirement was to concat the country code and corresponding city code like for **225** if city code column contain **120,123-129, 165-169** then values would be **225120,225123,225124,225125,225126,225127,225128,225129,225165,225166,225167,225168,225169**
So this is my original data base scenario. But there is one more thing if country code is 225 and city code is blank and 226 is another country code and city code is blank ,because city code will be blank for proper country code. So proper country code values would not be trim they will taken as **225,226** even if they are having same price. The values will be trim only in the case when city code are concated.

Is there any best way to do this with MySQL query.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand…

Comment: class like above 226 has single value not having more values between 220 and 229 so we take this value as 226 -  0.001 , And from 7565 to 7569 these numbers are coming in range of 7560-7569 and have same price so i will use grouping for these and get the common value756 and for 7583,7584,7585,7586 these are in range of 7580-7589 but have  two values of price so we can't use group for full range of code so it will be as its. I need trimming only if code coming between a range of ten and have same price.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to write this query in an index friendly way, so if it runs all the time you may want to restructure your data instead.

The query cuts codes down to 3 characters, I assume that's correct since 226 wasn't shortened.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Code,1,3) Code, Price FROM Test
GROUP BY SUBSTR(Code,1,3) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Price) = 1
UNION
SELECT Code, Price FROM Test WHERE SUBSTR(Code, 1, 3) IN
  (SELECT SUBSTR(Code,1,3) Code FROM Test
   GROUP BY SUBSTR(Code,1,3) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Price) > 1)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc10/2).

EDIT: After you updated your requirements, I think this will work with your dynamic lengths as long as the country codes are of constant length (3);

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Code,1,GREATEST(3,LENGTH(Code)-1)) Code, Price FROM Test
GROUP BY SUBSTR(Code,1,GREATEST(3,LENGTH(Code)-1)) 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Price) = 1
UNION
SELECT Code, Price FROM Test
WHERE SUBSTR(Code, 1, GREATEST(3,LENGTH(Code)-1)) IN
  (SELECT SUBSTR(Code,1,GREATEST(3,LENGTH(Code)-1)) Code FROM Test
   GROUP BY SUBSTR(Code,1,GREATEST(3,LENGTH(Code)-1)) 
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Price) > 1)
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d997/1).

Comment: hi joachim thanks for your answer and its working fine, and its cuts the code to 3 characters as you have already explained. But is there any way to make it dynamic..... if there are also values like 225345-225349

Comment: @Dinesh Yes, but in that case you need to clarify what the rules are for cutting the size down. Why isn't 226 cut down to 2 characters for example?

Comment: thanks for your reply i have edited the question with clear requirement Thanks

Comment: @Dinesh Updated answer with what I think is what you're asking for.

Comment: is there any way to work with dynamic country code like 225 or 2247 or 226  as i have given in the requirement and as i have explained you my initial database structure as country_code, city_code, full_code, full code will be having vales that will we get after combining the values one by one with city code and one row will have single values and with other rows the value of country code will be repeated

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. The following is a very inefficient query designed to step you through how to do it in a query. If it works like you want, you can optimize it:

```
select distinct code, price
from (
    select case when pricecount>1 then code else code10 end as code,
    price
    from test
    join (
        select code10, count(distinct(price)) as pricecount
        from (
            select floor(code/10) as code10, price
            from test
        ) a group by code10
    ) b
    on floor(test.code/10)=b.code10
) c;
```